# How to internal redirect subdomains using Apache ModRewrite?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#redirect

I'm trying to redirect all URL requests for my subdomains to `http://mydomain.com/gateway.php?%1/$1`.

For example, if the user request for http://sub.mydomain.com/page1.php, I want to perform an internal redirect to the page http://mydomain.com/gateway.php?sub.mydomain.com/page1.php.

Of course, the address bar should still show http://sub.mydomain.com/page1.php.

I currently use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!mydomain\.com)(.*) [nocase]
RewriteRule .* http://mydomain.com/gateway.php?%1/$1 [last,noescape]
```

Although the page displays correctly, the address bar was changed from http://sub.mydomain.com/page1.php to http://mydomain.com/gateway.php?sub.mydomain.com/page1.php.

How do I ensure that the redirect occurs internally?

Comment: _“How do I ensure that the redirect occurs internally?”_ – by _not_ using an _absolute_ replacement URL.

Comment: @CBroe, however, if I do not use absolute URL replacements, subdomain requests would be mapped back to the subdomain. I wish to map subdomain URL requests to the main domain.

Comment: How are subdomains implemented in your scenario? Are they pointing to different directories, or …? Fact is, if you do not want an external redirect, you can not use an absolute URL with a different hostname.